# Zsh "command not found" when running make TARGET

Tags: makefile, zsh

I'm using a makefile with two targets, both of which are variables. I can execute each target on the command line as follows:

`make $(TARGET)`

where TARGET is whatever file I'm outputting. However, before the target is made, zsh throws a "command not found" warning, which I assume means the shell is looking for a command called "TARGET" first. Is there a way to stop zsh from trying to find the command before `make` gets to it? I have tried both `make $(OUTPUT)` and `make "$(OUTPUT)"` and both cause the "command not found" warning.

Output for reference:

```
> make "$(OUTPUT)"
zsh: command not found: OUTPUT
make: 'the-contest.odt' is up to date.
```

Makefile for reference:

```
OUTPUT=the-contest.odt
FINAL=the-contest.html

$(OUTPUT): the-contest.md
    pandoc -o the-contest.odt the-contest.md

$(FINAL): the-contest.md
    pandoc -o the-contest.html the-contest.md
```

Comment: Single quotes do not interpolate.

Comment: `make "$(OUTPUT)"` first tries to run a program named _OUTPUT_. If this program would exist, the standard output would then be used as the target for `make`. For instance, if you define `OUTPUT() { echo the-contest.odt }; make "$(OUTPUT)"`, you would not get an error message and have `make` be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `$(some command)` in most shells means "run `some command` and substitute the output". So when you run `make "$(OUTPUT)"` you are asking your shell to run a command named `OUTPUT`, which is why you're getting a command not found error.

For what you're trying to do you probably want to restructure your Makefile, for example:

```
OUTPUT=the-contest.odt
FINAL=the-contest.html

.PHONY: output
output: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): the-contest.md
    pandoc -o the-contest.odt the-contest.md

$(FINAL): the-contest.md
    pandoc -o the-contest.html the-contest.md
```

Now you can run:

```
make output
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `make the-contest.odt` work with the original makefile as well?

Comment: Sure, but I assumed the goal was to have multiple Makefiles in different directories, and always be able to run `make output` without needing to know the name of the output file.

Comment: Part of the goal is flexibility so there's fewer places to change things. The main issue, admittedly, is "how do I avoid typing the filenames so much".